# Value is not setting while running but sets after hot restart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following situation: there is a `FutureBuilder` in my `build` method:

```
FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: NutritionDataManager().getDishes(),
            initialData: List(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Dish> dishes = snapshot.data.map((dish) {
                  return Dish(dish.id, dish.icon, dish.name, dish.gram, dish.calories, dish.time);
                }).toList();
                countTotalCalories(dishes);
                return SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return NutritionListItemWidget(
                        dish: snapshot.data[index],
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          )
```

This future gets data from database and if data is fetched (snapshot.hasData), it calls a method, which calculates something on the base of this data:

```
countTotalCalories(List<Dish> dishes) {
    int calSum = 0;
    dishes.forEach((dish) => calSum += dish.calories);    
    _currentCalories = calSum;        
  }
```

And after this value (`_currentCalories`) is used in another Widget. But when I run my app I always get zero value in `_currentCalories`, but then when I press hot restart, everything is ok. so, what's the matter f this problem and how can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

Here's the whole code of my screen:

```
class NutritionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NutritionScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NutritionScreenState createState() => _NutritionScreenState();
}

class _NutritionScreenState extends State<NutritionScreen> {
  int _currentCalories = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var date = "Aug 27";

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(AppColors.white),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(AppColors.brandViolet),
        onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          builder: (context) => BottomNutritionModal(),
        ),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0),
              child: Center(child: Text(date, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            floating: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
            ),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: _SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(
              child: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4),
                child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RichText(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          text: TextSpan(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: Dimensions.boldTextSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(text: "You have consumed \n"),
                              TextSpan(text: "500 out of 1900 cal", style: TextStyle(color: Color(AppColors.brandViolet))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: AnimatedCircularChart(
                            size: Size(constraints.maxHeight / 1.3, constraints.maxHeight / 1.3),
                            initialChartData: <CircularStackEntry>[
                              CircularStackEntry(
                                <CircularSegmentEntry>[
                                  CircularSegmentEntry(33.33, Color(AppColors.brandViolet)),
                                  CircularSegmentEntry(66.67, Color(AppColors.layoutBackgroundColor)),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                            chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
                            edgeStyle: SegmentEdgeStyle.round,
                            percentageValues: true,
                            holeLabel: "$_currentCalories",
                            labelStyle: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 35,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: NutritionDataManager().getDishes(),
            initialData: List(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Dish> dishes = snapshot.data.map((dish) {
                  return Dish(dish.id, dish.icon, dish.name, dish.gram, dish.calories, dish.time);
                }).toList();
                countTotalCalories(dishes);
                return SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return NutritionListItemWidget(
                        dish: snapshot.data[index],
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          )
        ]),
      ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(child: NutritionBottomInputWidget()),
    );
  }

  countTotalCalories(List<Dish> dishes) {
    int calSum = 0;
    dishes.forEach((dish) => calSum += dish.calories);
    setState(() {
      _currentCalories = calSum;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share `another Widget`, probably you are using statefulWidget right

Comment: Unchanged place inside `AnimatedCircularChart` right?, if yes can you share `AnimatedCircularChart` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code might help you. put _currentCalories inside setState method.

```
 countTotalCalories(List<Dish> dishes) {
  int calSum = 0;
  dishes.forEach((dish) => calSum += dish.calories);
  if (mounted){
    setState(() {
      _currentCalories = calSum;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Still get the same exception

Comment: @Sergei Mikhailovskii I think data takes time to load into dishes list but countTotalCalories function call before data fetch. That's why you get zero value and when you press hot restart data is already fetched.

Comment: Use debugger to find data flow.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put

```
_currentCalories = calSum;
```

in a setState ?

Comment: Yes, but in such case I get the following error: `The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<dynamic>>#c3a6b):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

Comment: wrap it with an if clause that checks this.mounted

Comment: @MuratAslan, unfortunately didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you cant share `AnimatedCircularChart`, problem is could be like that

If you dont use your `AnimatedCircularChart` widget like this, tell me please and i ll update answer.

This is your usage,

```
AnimatedCircularChart(
  ...
  holeLabel: "$_currentCalories", // ***
  ...
)
```

I expect `AnimatedCircularChart` like this,

[image: Here]

You need to override `didUpdateWidget` like that,

[image: Here]